# Can't access MongoDB cluster in AWS VPC Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vpc

I have a Node app running on Elastic Beanstalk.

I also have a CloudFormation MongoDB cluster with 1 replica. I can connect to this directly by using the ec2 private IP 111.22.3.44 it's named PrimaryReplicaNode0.

However I keep getting MongoDB master slave errors so I don't think I'm supposed to connect to this directly. Which address am I supposed to use from within Elastic Beanstalk to connect?

Do I connect directly to the EC2 replica address or do I use a subnet of some sort?

Both the MongoDB cluster and Elastic Beanstalk servers are in the same VPC.

```
Connected to mongodb named app1 at 172.00.1.XX
Express https server listening on port 8081 in development mode
{ [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.00.1.XX:27017]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 172.00.1.XX:27017' }
```

Comment: When do you get the error? while performing operation or while connecting to read replica?

Comment: I assume by EBS you mean Elastic Beanstalk? EBS actually stands for Elastic Block Store.

Comment: performing operation. I added the output above